# How to build boost library (program options) without using bjam

Tags: visual-c++, boost, g++, compilation, bjam

I need to build boost program options static library in both PC/Mac.
It has only 11 cpp source code, so I expect to compile it by `g++ SOURCE_CODE`, but I got  an error something like `utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp:15:47: error: ../../detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp: No such file or directory`.

How to build boost library (program options) without using bjam? Is there a way to see what compiler options/commands bjam uses for both Mac/PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bjam -n` will print the commands instead of executing them.  `bjam -d 2` will print the commands as they are executed.

http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/jam/usage.html

http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html